# There's no error but take-profit functions on short trades aren't working

Tags: pine-script, trading, algorithmic-trading, pine-script-v5

So basically, the take-profit function on long trades works flawlessly, but it's not working on the short trades. It's my first time dealing with pine-script, so I've no idea what I am doing wrong.

```
entrySize = 2
trimSize = entrySize / 2
nytp = 0.003
ontp = 0.0015


//Calculating Time
nySession = time(timeframe.period, "0930-1600")
onSession = time(timeframe.period, "1800-0930")


//NY Session Take Profit
nyLongTP = strategy.position_avg_price * (1 + nytp)
nyShortTP = strategy.position_avg_price * (1 - nytp)


//ON Session Take Profit
onLongTP = strategy.position_avg_price * (1 + ontp)
onShortTP = strategy.position_avg_price * (1 - ontp)
 
    
//Take Profit Long
if (strategy.position_avg_price > 0)
    if (nySession)
        strategy.order(id = "Long", direction = strategy.short, qty = trimSize, limit = nyLongTP, comment = "LTP")

    if (onSession)
        strategy.order(id = "Long", direction = strategy.short, qty = trimSize, limit = onLongTP, comment = "LTP")

//Take Profit Short
if (strategy.position_avg_price < 0)
    if (nySession)
        strategy.order(id = "Short", direction = strategy.long, qty = trimSize, limit = nyShortTP, comment = "STP")
    
    if (onSession)
        strategy.order(id = "Short", direction = strategy.long, qty = trimSize, limit = onShortTP, comment = "STP")
```

I'm expecting the short trade to close 50% of the quantity at the limit price that is provided by "nyShortTP" & "onShortTP" but the limit order is not getting placed.

Answer (score 0):

Well your condition seems to be wrong. I think you're looking for [strategy.position_size](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/v5/#var_strategy%7Bdot%7Dposition_size) instead of strategy.position_avg_price.
Now you're evaluating:

> Average entry price of current market position. If the market position is flat, 'NaN' is returned.

[reference](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/v5/#var_strategy%7Bdot%7Dposition_avg_price)
and this should be basically < 0. Is that even possible?
Generally, to check if you ever get into a situation, you could always print a label for yourself, like:

```
if strategy.position_avg_price < 0  
    label.new(bar_index, high, "Yeah condition's true")
```

Back to the question and the solution:
I think you are looking for something else. If it's the direction of your positions you're interested in, then use `strategy.position_size`. Already discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73592846/15348203).